# Using Custom .ttf Font Throught the Website

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a font named "Contempory___Modern_Font_by_MyFox.ttf" (Font can be found here: [Download Contemporary Modern Font](http://myfox.deviantart.com/art/Contempory-Modern-Font-96177874)

I want to use this font through out a site that i am developing for myself.

I have tried the @font-face{}, but still unable to see the site fonts being displayed like in the font.

my code for the @font-face{} is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Custom Font";
    src: url(font/Contempory___Modern_Font_by_MyFox.ttf);
}
```

How can I achieve showing this font on all the pages of the site? I am using Dreamweaver CS5 to code my website, it is in simple HTML. Please suggest!

Comment: Incomplete information: rest of CSS and all of HTML missing, browser(s) tested not identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use .woff formate font for website.

In some of the browser .ttf create issue.

You can convert the .ttf font to .woff

[HERE](http://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff)

Try this

HOW TO LOAD AND USE IT:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "NameForFontFamily";
    src: url(fonts/fontfilename.woff);
}
```

in style of html DOM use:

```
font-family: NameForFontFamily;
```

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
<a class='addfont' href="#" style="font-family:NameForFontFamily;">CLICK ME</a>

OR

.addfont{
     font-family:NameForFontFamily;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate webfonts for use within the font-face tags ..

Try this - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator